# point CDK CodePipelineSource to GitHub repo subfolder

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

Is there a way to point CDK CodePipelineSource to a subfolder of a GitHub repo? I only want my CodePipeline to be triggered on changes in a specific subfolder in the repo.
My current setup:

```
const githubConnection = CodePipelineSource.connection(
  'ExampleOrg/ToolsRepo',
  'main',
  {
    connectionArn: 'arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-west-2:4539727446:connection/jchfjd-hfjksdfhs-kdfjksd-fhjskdlf',
    triggerOnPush: true
  }
);

const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  pipelineName: 'cdk-pipeline-test',
  crossAccountKeys: true,
  synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
    input: githubConnection,
    primaryOutputDirectory: 'cdk-pipeline/cdk.out',
    commands: ['cd ./cdk-pipeline','npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth']        
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly. AWS have a [blog post explaining how to do it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrate-github-monorepo-with-aws-codepipeline-to-run-project-specific-ci-cd-pipelines/) though.

Basically you trigger a lambda from the github change and that control which pipelines, if any, are started.